# How to get value under the last column of an SQL ouput

Tags: regex, text-processing

I've piped the result of an SQL query to a log file and I'm having problems getting the 119 GB value under the Free Space Column.

```
 [echo] SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Oct 1 13:39:19 2014
 [echo] 
 [echo] Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
 [echo] 
 [echo] 
 [echo] Connected to:
 [echo] Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
 [echo] 
 [echo] 
 [echo] Database Size        Used space       Free space
 [echo] -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
 [echo] 126 GB           7 GB         119 GB
 [echo] 
 [echo] SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

The above output and more (i.e. typical SQL output) is all stored in an Ant Variable. I'm having problems getting the last chunk of the above piece - i.e. just the 119 GB under the Free Space. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: post some more lines.

Comment: pipe to `sed -n 's/\[echo\]\s*\d*\sGB\s*\d*\sGB\s*\(\d*\)\sGB/\1/p'` maybe?

Comment: This is running on a windows box currently so can't really run sed.

Answer (score 0):

You can (still) get this with AWK, although after your edit it's more of a hack than anything:

```
BEGIN {
    RS = "\n"
}

/Database Size/ {
    r = NR + 2
}

(NR == r) {
    nfm1 = NF - 1
    print $nfm1, $NF
}
```

Comment: I think regex is probably the easiest way to get what I need. I'm running a batch file from an ANT script that I wrote so once I have the above output stored in my log, I was thinking of using the propertyRegex task to get what I needed. However, the regex expression for getting the 119 GB is really tripping me up.

Comment: This was from before you added context

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us more about you computer is this linux or Windows? Do you want answer in Java or Bash?

Anyway regex for last GB of the line is:

```
[0-9]+\sGB$
```

Comment: It's running on a windows machine. I'm just looking for a regex expression that I use with the propertyregex ant task. I tried what you posted above, but it returned this: 

          `[echo] Database Size      Used space    Free space
     [echo] -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
     [echo] 126 GB       7 GB    119 GB
     [echo] 
     [echo] SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
     [echo]  FREE SPACE: ${free_space}`

Comment: I have to addmit that I am not familiar with ant taks, or anythign windows realted, but try my updated regex.  There probaily are few more way of doing this but is hard to know for me without trying it out your machine.

Comment: @Mosinel, tested and works with `egrep '[0-9]{3}\sGB$' -o` or `egrep '[0-9]+\sGB$' -o`, given what you have posted.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Thanks a lot! That worked. Although, after I perform that operation. I close my SQL instance. When that happens, it breaks the Regex since there are a couple of lines after the 119 GB. Is there a way to ignore everything after that 119 GB? I've updated the original post to include the extra lines.

Comment: It _shouldn't_ break the regex. And indeed it doesnt, since I just tried it with the extra lines and it worked fine. I just saw you're on a Windows computer, so I don't know what you're using in place of `egrep` and I can't account for its behavior.